# Interrupting connect call through shutdown of local socket?

Tags: c++, sockets, tcp, network-programming

A C connect call blocks until its success or failure. This may take some while.
If I need to have a timeout on the connect, is it a proper solution to shut down the (not yet established) connection by using shutdown on the own end of the connection?

This example code shows the idea.

```c++
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>

#include <future>
#include <iostream>

void Connect(int sock) {
  struct sockaddr_in addr = {};
  addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
  addr.sin_port = htons(12345);
  addr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("X.X.X.X"); // IP that does not (immediately) send RST
  memset(addr.sin_zero, '\0', sizeof addr.sin_zero);

  connect(sock, (sockaddr*)(&addr), sizeof(sockaddr_in));
}

int main() {
  int sock = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
  auto f = std::async(std::launch::async, [sock]{
    Connect(sock);
    std::cout << "Connect returned" << std::endl;
  } );
  if (f.wait_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(500)) == std::future_status::timeout) {
    std::cout << "Connect timeout" << std::endl;
    shutdown(sock, SHUT_RDWR); // blocks here if commented out
  } else {
    std::cout << "Connect success" << std::endl;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

To clarify: This solution seems to work. I mainly want to know whether this is good/standard way of satisfy the need of giving up on a connect. (I used a DNS server on the internet with a random port for my test).

Comment: Don't tag unrelated languages. (Fixed.)

Comment: All used network functions are C: socket(), connect(), shutdown(). 
The question is only about these functions. 
std::async & the lambda function is only used to provide a working example. One could easily convert this to pure C using threads.

Comment: One could easily convert many programs into many languages.

Comment: A better approach is to put the socket into non-blocking mode during the connect() call, and then use select() or poll()/epoll() to handle the timeout. No thread needed. If the connect is successful, you can put the socket back into blocking mode if desired.

Comment: @ikegami How about the main point: "All used network functions are C: socket(), connect(), shutdown(). The question is only about these functions." ?

Comment: C has similar functions, but this is a C++ program

Answer (score 1):

`shutdown` should only be called on a connected socket, i.e. after a successful call to `connect`.  Doing otherwise will cause `shutdown` to return -1 to indicate an error and set `errno` to `ENOTCONN`.

In either case, you'll want to `close` the socket when you're done with it.